# Prove that $f : \mathbb{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\} \to X$ exists

Tags: set-theory

> Prove that for every nonempty set $X$ there exists a function $f : \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}\to X$ such that for every nonempty $A \subseteq X, f(A)\in A.$

Let $X$ be a nonempty set. For every $A\in \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\},$ Let $Y_A = \{A\}\times A.$ Then $Y_{A_1} \cap Y_{A_2}=\emptyset$ when $A_1 \neq A_2.$ So $Z = \{Y_A : A\in \mathcal{P}(X)\}$ is a set of pairwise disjoint sets. Thus, by the axiom of choice, there exists a set $f := \{(A, Y_A) : A\in\mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\},Y_A \in A\}.$ This is precisely the function we are seeking.

> How can $Y_A \in A$ if $Y_A = \{A\}\times A$? Am I getting the definition wrong?

Comment: Prove from... what?

Comment: Presumably https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97222/3-statements-of-axiom-of-choice-are-equivalent contains an answer to your question, depending on how you formulated the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing but Axiom of Choice.

By Axiom of Choice we can pick an element from each non-empty subset $A$ of $X$.  Just call this element $f(A)$ and you get your function.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading. The Axiom of Choice is formulated in ***a lot*** of ways, and the above is one of them. So the question is now *how did they OPs source formulated AC*.